# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'corpus_or_AB_FMC.xlsx'

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, excel, pandas

I have a directory which contains a lot of excel files. My aim is to read all those excel files and extract some information in them. I used the script below to read the directory but I am still getting an error. The files are identified but the code tell it is not founding them which is strange because there is a line to print the name of the file. But when reading the file with pandas, it is not founded.

```
/home/geta/kelo/eXP/Test/corpus
-----File in processed : corpus_or_AB_FMC.xlsx
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test_vec.py", line 111, in <module>
    sentences = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name= 0)
  File "/home/getalp/kelodjoe/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py", line 208, in wrapper
    return func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/home/geta/kelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 310, in read_excel
    io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
  File "/home/geta/kelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 819, in __init__
    self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
  File "/home/geta/kelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlrd.py", line 21, in __init__
    super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/home/geta/kelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py", line 359, in __init__
    self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/home/geta/kelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlrd.py", line 36, in load_workbook
    return open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
  File "/home/geta/kelo/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/xlrd/__init__.py", line 111, in open_workbook
    with open(filename, "rb") as f:
```

here is the code :

```
dir = "/home/geta/kelo/eXP/Test/corpus"
for root, subdirs, files in os.walk(dir):
    print(root)
    for file in files:
        #print(files)
        print("-----File in processed :", file)
        # -----File in processed : corpus_or_AB_FMC.xlsx  # this file si located in the corpus directory
        sentences = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name= 0)
        data_id = sentences.identifiant
        print("Total phrases: ", len(data_id))
        data = sentences.verbatim

        data_label = sentences.etiquette
        #print(type(data_id))
        #print(type(data))
        #number = LabelEncoder()
        # 0 = C; 1= F; 2= M
        #data_label = number.fit_transform(sentences.etiquette.astype('str'))
        #print(data_label)
        
        print("etiquette  :" , sentences['etiquette'].unique())
        classes = sentences['etiquette'].unique()
        len_classes = len(classes)
```

Answer (score 1):

`file` is a file's name and does not include the path to it. Use `os.path.join`:

```
sentences = pd.read_excel(os.path.join(root, file), sheet_name=0)
```

to join the file name and its absolute path.